# Spring ORM 4 - SpringSessionSynchronization.afterCompletion no longer calls SessionImplementor.afterTransactionCompletion

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, spring-orm

We are currently upgrading our codebase from Hibernate 3/Spring ORM 3 to version 4 for both (Hibernate 4.3.7/Spring ORM 4.2.6).  After upgrading, we found that the Hibernate query cache is no longer working as expected, as the update timestamps cache is not being invalidated after a commit.

From comparing version 3 and 4, the issue seems to be in `SpringSessionSynchronization.afterCompletion`.  This method in version 4 no longer calls `SessionImplementor.afterTransactionCompletion` (which used to ensure the update timestamps cache is invalidated).  Can anyone suggest how we are supposed to achieve this functionality now?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would review release 4.3.11 to see whether that behavior still exists on the last release on that branch stream.  Otherwise, my suggestion would be to move to at least a community supported stream of Hibernate, preferably something in the 5.x release line like 5.2 if possible.

Comment: I have tried version 5.2 (although it's not fully supported in the firm that I work hence only upgrading to 4.x), but I still found the same issue.  I'm a bit mystified as to how something so fundamental could have changed without others running into the same issue.